# Getting amount of memory processes usage from 'ps aux' output with awk in MB

Tags: awk, ps

I`m newbie with Linux so... I have a exercise to do: using only ps, grep, awk, gawk determine total amount of memory processes used by SQL. How i can determine with ps how much memory used by any process? Mem in ps displaying  in percents...
Thanks alot.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Have you tried running ps *and looking at the output*? The output format varies a bit from system to system, so you'll have to tailor `grep` & co. to your situation.

Comment: I`m using ubuntu 11.04, and yes, im trying running ps auwx, mem in percent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ps auwx | awk '/[s]ql/ {total += $4} END {print total}'
```

You might want to look for `$11 ~ /sql/` instead to find actual (my)sql processes instead of any command with "sql" in any argument.